# How to make the div scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

By clicking the button, the div should be popup and scrollable. The div just static in middle when I scroll down. I have changed the css position:fixed, still no luck. Help me to make the div scrollable.

```
<button onClick="openPopup();">click here</button>
<div id="test" class="popup">
    <div class="cancel" onclick="closePopup();"></div>
</div>

<style>
.popup{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width: 1250px;
    height: 750px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:2px;
    background-color:white;
    border:2px solid grey;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
    display:none;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); 
    }

.cancel{
    display:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    height:10px;
    width:14px;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:11px;
    color:white;
    border-radius:3px;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
    }   
.cancel:hover{
    background:rgb(255,50,50);
    }
</style>

<script>
function openPopup() {
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';
}
function closePopup() {
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
}    
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one:

```
<div class="popup" style="overflow: auto;">
```

Or alternatively in CSS file:

```
.popup {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

The value `auto` in the `overflow` property will show a scroll bar if the content is overflowed. If you use the `scroll` value, it will show the scroll bar even the content of the element is not overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:-

```
.popup{ overflow:scroll; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
<button onClick="openPopup();">click here</button>
<div id="test" class="popup" style="overflow: scroll;">
    <div class="cancel" onclick="closePopup();"></div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>
<style>
.popup{
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:2px;
    background-color:white;
    border:2px solid grey;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
    display:none;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); 
    }

.cancel{
    display:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    height:10px;
    width:14px;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:11px;
    color:white;
    border-radius:3px;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
}   
.cancel:hover{
    background:rgb(255,50,50);
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function openPopup() {
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';
}
function closePopup() {
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
}    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8hZW/):

I think you wanted the div to be fixed, when you scroll the page. I have changed the popup's height & width. Just for the sake of testing added height to body. You can remove it.

```
.popup{
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  z-index: 100000000000000000;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```